# What does the Joker say in Tim Burton's Batman (1989)?

Tags: dc, batman, the-joker

I don't understand what does the Joker says in this scene from [Tim Burton's Batman movie in 1989](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Batman_(1989_film)).

It sounds to me like:

> "I'm of a mind to make some mookie"

but that doesn't make sense to me. What does the Joker say and what does he mean?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The line is: "I'm of a mind to make some mooky."

This is from [the transcript](https://web.archive.org/web/20140909164807/http://www.springfieldspringfield.co.uk/movie_script.php?movie=batman).

"Mooky" seems to have several meanings; however the most likely meaning, given he is holding a picture of Vicki Vale and has just talked about her beauty, is that he wants to [have sex](http://www.definition-of.com/Mooky).

The line is slightly altered from the [production script](https://sfy.ru/?script=batman_production):

> THE CAMERA PULLS BACK to reveal that the JOKER is surrounded, wall to wall, by a collage of pictures of war
> and destruction.  The huge collage forms a birds-eye-view map of Gotham.
>
> JOKER
> I've got a mind to make some mayhem.  Phone book!

Comment: It probably is mookie — the Joker is always making boners too: https://screenrant.com/joker-boner-comic-meme/amp/

Comment: The line in the novelisation is "*“Phone book! I’ve got a mind to make some mayhem.”*"

Answer (score 2):

You have the quote correct, though the word might also be "moogie." From googling around, it seems the consensus is that "make mookie" means the same as "make love" (ie have sex). Similar to the phrase "make whoopie."

However, I also saw where someone claimed that "make mookie eyes" at someone means to flirt with them.

Either way, both definitions imply romantic (or at least lustful) intent. Given that he's looking at a picture of Vicky Vale at the same time, I'm incline to believe that's the case here. And my money is on the first definition.

Comment: +1 Also similar to "make nookie".

Answer (score 0):

While the script might have left the line at that, if you read Mr Nicholson's lips as he delivers it, it comes out "I'm of a mind makes a movie."

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Even if they redubbed the line, the question was about the movie as released; do you have any evidence this is the intended line?

Comment: That isn't grammatical English.